A Question about implementation of Perfect Forward Secrecy
How can be Perfect Forward Secrecy explained in the context of tor network?
How does the concept of Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS) apply to onion routing, and why is it critical for the security of the TOR network?

Onion routing is SSL inside SSL inside SSL,and each connection's session key is negotiated point-to-point in the process of the pipe construction

I don't see how this answers the question.  SSL (or TLS) doesn't inherently provide perfect forward secrecy (see here for more info).  Also, Tor uses TLS, not SSL.  Also, it doesn't address the part about why it matters for Tor security (see this reddit post for some information on that).

As it said in Wikipedia with a simple but sufficient explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy - TLS uses Diffie-Hellman to achieve that. And Tor is a 3-layered pipe that looks like an onion on the cut, so the outer pipe is used for the inner pipe negotiation et cetera

That information should be in the answer, but also, quoting from that very same Wikipedia article: "in everyday practice many implementations refused to offer forward secrecy".  It then goes on to note that TLS 1.3 fixes this.  However, TLS 1.3 was released in 2018, well after Tor, and there's no assertion that Tor has since upgraded to TLS 1.3 (in fact, this answer seems to explicitly say otherwise, referring to SSL rather than TLS).
